# Unterschied von "Performance" und "Performanz"

Tags: translation

Wsa ist der Unterschied zwischen **Performance<sub>DE</sub>** und **Performanz<sub>DE</sub>**? Was ich weiß, ist, dass **performance<sub>EN</sub>** die englische Übersetzung von **Performanz<sub>DE</sub>** im Deutschen ist. Das würde nahelegen, dass **Performance<sub>DE</sub>** lediglich eine Eindeutschung des englischen Wortes und Begriffs wäre. Allerdings denke ich, diese Wort des Öfteren schon im Zusammenhang von **Entertaining** gehört zu haben: *Das war eine gute Performance von dir!*

Comment: Das kommt sehr darauf an, in welchem Fachgebiet du dich bewegst.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance) erklärt den Unterschied zwischen [Performance (Kunst)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance_(Kunst)) und Performance = [Rechenleistung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rechenleistung) sowie die jeweilige Herkunft ganz gut.

Comment: Inwiefern ist der letzte Satz ein "Allerdings". "Performance" (EN) hat auch hier die gleiche Bedeutung wie im Deutschen.

Answer (score 2):

Generell gelten diese Bedeutungen und Verwendungsarten:

### Performance

Aussprache: [pəˈfɔːməns] (mittlere Silbe betont)
Direkt aus dem Englischen importiert, unter (weitgehender) Erhaltung der englischen Aussprache. Es ist also ein Fremdwort.

1. Eine künstlerische Darbietung

   > Ich werde heute Abend eine **Performance** der Tanzgruppe Humpelbein besuchen.
2. Wertentwicklung eines Wertpapiers

   > Die **Performance** des DAX lag im letzten Quartal unter den Erwartungen der Analysten.
3. Leistung in der Informationstechnik

   > Grund für die schlechte **Performance** der Datenbank sind überflüssige Fremdschlüsselverknüpfungen.

---

### Performanz

Aussprache: [ˌpɛʁfɔʁˈmanʦ] (letzte Silbe betont)
Eingedeutschte Version des englischen Wortes »performance«. Sowohl Schreibweise als auch Aussprache wurden den deutschen Gepflogenheiten angepasst. Es ist also ein Lehnwort.

1. In der Linquistik: Das Sprechen, bzw. die individuelle Sprachverwendung

   > Für Chomsky kann die Erforschung der **Performanz** nur in dem Maße Erfolg haben, wie es Einsichten in die zugrunde liegende Kompetenz erlauben.
2. In der Mathematik: Qualität eines Näherungalgorithmus

   > Das Newtonverfahren bietet in den meisten Fällen eine deutlich höhere **Performanz** als die Intervalteilung

---

Diese Trennung ist aber äußerst schwach. Gerne wird das eine Wort auch als Synonym für das andere verwendet. Die oben aufgelisteten Bedeutungen und Beispiele könnten also auch beim jeweils anderen Wort stehen.

Comment: Die künstlerische Darbietung ist meiner Meinung nach immer eine *Performance*, keine *Performanz*. Bei den anderen Beispielen (gemeinsame Umschreibung: "Leistung") sind die beiden Wörter allerdings in der Tat ziemlich austauschbar.